# Start of the month and end of the month filter

Tags: apache-superset

I want to apply a filter which should start from every month 01 00:00:01 to next month 01 00:00:01, how this can be achieved using apache superset advanced filter or any other means,

Superset version I am using is 2.0.0

I have tried Date_trunc, dateadd, datetime etc, none of them are supporting

Answer (score 1):

I use the date filter, TIME RANGE, option ADVANCED

**Start(Inclusive):** *Previous Month + 1 Month*

**End(Exclusive):** *Next Month*

You enter the text above as is.
So, I get the following date range (based on today April 25th, 2023):

```
Actual time range
2023-04-01 ≤ col < 2023-05-01
```

which gives me a date range from the first of the month to the last day of this month.